# Checking if values are not empty for dynamically created textboxes

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a code piece that generates id dynamically as checc1, checc2 etc for each dynamically created textboxes respectively. How can I get these values to the variable boxc one by one?

```
 function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
  var nextRowID = 0;
  var id = ++nextRowID;
  return value+' : '+'<input class="dynfield" name = "'+value+'" id="checc' + id + '" type="text" value = "" />' + '<input type="hidden" name="fieldnames[]" value="'+value+'"/>' + '<br>' + '<br>' 
}
```

This is my code right now and it is wrong. This is the code in which I need the values of checc for performing validation to those dynamically created text boxes. Should I use a loop?

```
function boxCheck() {        

  var boxc = $('#checc').val();

  if (boxc.length == 0) {
    $('#p9').text("* Cannot be blank *");
    $("#checc").parents(".chenn").addClass("error");
    return false;
  } else {
    $("#checc").parents(".chenn").removeClass("error");
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `var id = 1; var boxc = $('#checc' + id).val();` ?

Comment: works for only one dynamically created textbox. Validation not getting applied from 2nd textbox on wards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the inputs using the class of inputs.

```
$('.dynfield').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).val(); //append them to var boxc or do the processing you want
});
```

To check if all of your inputs have some value

```
function boxCheck() {
    $('.dynfield').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != '') { 
            //Errors.push("Please select a vehicle"); 
            $('#p9').text("* Cannot be blank *"); 
            $(this).parents(".chenn").addClass("error"); 
            return false; 
        } else {
            $(this).parents(".chenn").removeClass("error"); 
            return true; 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: function boxCheck() {
$('.dynfield').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

     if (value.length == 0)

            {
                //Errors.push("Please select a vehicle");
                $('#p9').text("* Cannot be blank *");
                    $("#checc").parents(".chenn").addClass("error");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $("#checc").parents(".chenn").removeClass("error");
                    return true;
                }
            

    
});

} like this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? check if atleast one input has value? or check if all inputs have value?

Comment: if all inputs have values...if i have 10 input boxes, all 10 should have values....or else display error...

Comment: Updated answer @serializer